# Match and merge two data frames

Tags: r

I want to merge and match the following CSV files.

**CSV 1**

```
Year    Qrtrs   BD  BS  BY  All
1950    JAS     0   1   0   1
1950    OND     0   2   1   3
1951    JAS     1   0   4   5
```

**CSV 2**

```
Year    JFM AMJ JAS OND
1950    LN  LN  NN  LN
1951    LN  NN  EN  EN
```

And would like to get the ff.

```
Year    Qrtrs   CASE    BD  BS  BY  All
1950    JAS       NN    0   1   0   1
1950    OND       LN    0   2   1   3
1951    JAS       EN    1   0   4   5
```

I am new to R.Thank you for your help.

And also, I want to add the remaining Qrtrs in the final CSV and just put "0" in BD,BS,BY,ALL. Pls see below.

```
Year    Qrtrs   CASE    BD  BS  BY  All
1950    JAS       NN    0   1   0   1
1950    OND       LN    0   2   1   3
1950    AMJ       LN    0   0   0   0
1950    JFM       LN    0   0   0   0
```

Thank you.!

Comment: what is the logic to get `CASE` column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 2):

#### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(
  text = "Year    Qrtrs   BD  BS  BY  All
          1950    JAS     0   1   0   1
          1950    OND     0   2   1   3
          1951    JAS     1   0   4   5",
  header = T, stringsAsFactors = F
)

df2 <- read.table(
  text = "Year    JFM AMJ JAS OND
          1950    LN  LN  NN  LN
          1951    LN  NN  EN  EN",
  header = T, stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

I provide a method with `gather{tidyr}` and `left_join{dplyr}` :

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df2.2 <- gather(df2, key = "Qrtrs", value = "CASE", - Year)

df2.2

#   Year Qrtrs CASE
# 1 1950   JFM   LN
# 2 1951   JFM   LN
# 3 1950   AMJ   LN
# 4 1951   AMJ   NN
# 5 1950   JAS   NN
# 6 1951   JAS   EN
# 7 1950   OND   LN
# 8 1951   OND   EN

left_join(df1, df2.2)

#   Year Qrtrs BD BS BY All CASE
# 1 1950   JAS  0  1  0   1   NN
# 2 1950   OND  0  2  1   3   LN
# 3 1951   JAS  1  0  4   5   EN
```

---

Additionally, here is a base way :

```
df2.stack <- stack(df2, select = -Year)
df2.2 <- cbind(df2$Year, df2.stack)
names(df2.2) <- c("Year", "CASE", "Qrtrs")
merge(df1, df2.2, by = c("Year", "Qrtrs"))
```